# Send HDMI commands through laptop HDMI connector

Tags: command-line, hdmi

There is any way to send HDMI commands through laptop HDMI connector? Not using the HDMI USB-CEC, directly trough the HDMI connector.

I need to send the REC / STOP command to a recorder from the laptop. 
It can be done with any camera conected trough HDMI, once you click REC on the camera, the recorder start to record.

Thanks guys!

Comment: This might be helpful: [How to control a TV from Linux? - Super User](https://superuser.com/q/1064210/443564)